# He has/having a bad connection

Tags: tense

If I want to describe someone, that at the moment, experiencing a bad internet connection, what should I say?

> He **has/having** a bad connection.

Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**He having a bad connection** doesn't have a main verb, so it doesn't work.

**He is having a bad connection** works. So does **He has a bad connection**. They differ slightly: *He is having...* means the connection is currently bad, but doesn't say whether this often happens. *He has...* means the connection is often bad, but doesn't say whether it's bad right now.